# ExecuteReader attempting to execute procedure that should not be executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, clr

I'm attempting to create a CLR that will return the column meta-data of the results of a query sent to it. However, I'm getting an error saying `Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.Custom_My_Proc'`. However, the EXEC statement for this procedure would only ever be hit IF the procedure existed in the first place.

For example,

```
IF ( Object_ID('dbo.Custom_My_Proc') IS NOT NULL ) EXEC dbo.Custom_My_Proc
```

I believe this is coming from the use of `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly`, but from what I've read this is what I need to be using in this case. I've attempted to use `Commandbehavior.KeyInfo` instead, but this started having issues with my "debugging" PRINT statements. Here is the full code from the CLR:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class Procedure2DataDict
{
    private class ProcResult
    {
        public SqlString ColumnName;
        public SqlInt32 ColumnSize;
        public SqlInt32 NumericPrecision;
        public SqlInt32 NumericScale;
        public SqlString DataTypeName;

        public ProcResult(SqlString columnName, SqlInt32 columnSize, SqlInt32 numericPrecision, SqlInt32 numericScale, SqlString dataTypeName)
        {
            ColumnName = columnName;
            ColumnSize = columnSize;
            NumericPrecision = numericPrecision;
            NumericScale = numericScale;
            DataTypeName = dataTypeName;
        }
    }

    [SqlFunction(
       DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, 
       SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read,
       FillRowMethodName = "GetColumnData_FillRow",
       TableDefinition = "ColumnName varchar(100), ColumnSize int, NumericPrecision int, NumericScale int, DataTypeName varchar(100)")]
    public static IEnumerable Return_ColumnData(SqlString proc)
    {
        ArrayList resultCollection = new ArrayList();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sProc = proc.ToString();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.Generic_Data_Return @ps_ProcedureName", connection))
            {
                SqlParameter ProcedureNameParam = command.Parameters.Add("@ps_ProcedureName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
                ProcedureNameParam.Value = sProc;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
                {
                    var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                    foreach (DataRow myField in schema.Rows)
                    {
                        resultCollection.Add(new ProcResult(
                                myField[0].ToString(),
                                Convert.ToInt32(myField[2]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(myField[3]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(myField[4]),
                                myField[24].ToString()
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultCollection;
    }
    public static void GetColumnData_FillRow(
        object procResultObj
        , out SqlString columnName
        , out SqlInt32 columnSize
        , out SqlInt32 numericPrecision
        , out SqlInt32 numericScale
        , out SqlString dataTypeName)
    {
        ProcResult procResult = (ProcResult)procResultObj;

        columnName = procResult.ColumnName;
        columnSize = procResult.ColumnSize;
        numericPrecision = procResult.NumericPrecision;
        numericScale = procResult.NumericScale;
        dataTypeName = procResult.DataTypeName;

    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to have this CLR either ignore any PRINT/SET/etc... or not execute procedures within the procedure if they do not exist?

Comment: You've defined a CLR sql function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: The presence of the objects involved is checked at compile time in SQL server. So your `IF` doesn't matter in that regard. You can "disguise" the call by using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Does stored procedure run with SQL Server Management Studio with same user credentials?  SSMS give much better error messages than c#.  The store procedure may not have the correct credentials to run with the credentials in the connection string.

Comment: @stickybit As in running the function with dSQL instead of using command.Parameters.Add()?

Comment: @jdweng Yeah, the exact SQL statement runs just fine in SSMS

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, my issue is coming from the CLR

Comment: In SQL, where ever that `IF .. EXEC ...` is.

Comment: I'm saying you can't `exec` a function, you `select` it.